# Transfer vs. transmit

Tags: word-usage, single-word-requests, word-choice

What is the difference between transfer and transmit ; 
E.g
Anyone who transports, transfers, transmits or receives illegal money commits an offense.

Comment: These are all Latin words, and were formed in Latin before they were borrowed (at different times, for different purposes) into English. But the original etymologies are still useful. _Trans-_ means 'across, between', and sets up a motion frame from A to B. The verbs are _portare_ 'carry', _ferre_ 'bear, carry', and _mittere_ 'send'. So _transport_ and _transfer_ both imply completion from A to B. But _transmit_ only applies to A, where the sending happens; nothing is implied about B.

Comment: In legalese it's quite common to list a bunch of synonyms for some activity/concept, so a bad guy can't say "I wasn't transporting the stolen mercendise, I was transmitting it", and claim some finely-drawn definition of "transport" that seems to let him off the hook.

Comment: Did you check a dictionary?

Comment: *I checked in Advanced English Dictionary and Thesaurus (online version)*                                         transfer move from one place to another "transfer the data" "transmit the news" "transfer the patient to another hospital"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider how the money gets from point A to point B.

If you [transport](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transport) the money, you are carrying it, perhaps in a briefcase or duffel bag. You have cash in hand.

> transport: to carry, move, or convey from one place to another.

If you [transfer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transfer?s=t) the money, you are probably using a paper check or wiring money through your bank. You're probably using your pen or phone to convey the money (with no cash in hand), although *transfer* does not exclude a briefcase.

> transfer: to convey or remove from one place, person, etc., to another

If you [transmit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transmit?s=t) the money, then you are probably making a [wire transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_transfer) or paying by check or money order. The briefcase is not in the picture. There is no cash in hand.

> transmit: to send or forward, as to a recipient or destination; dispatch; convey.

Answer (score 11):

Forgetting money for a moment:

*Transfer* implies both transmission and reception.  It is the process of moving something from A to B successfully.

*Transmit* implies sending something away without necessarily knowing where it will end up, e.g. Television transmission.

*Receive* is the complement of transmit.

Thus, in your example of money laundering:
A person *transmits* money by giving it to a courier, who in turn *transfers* it to a person who is a *receiver*.

Of course, the *transfer* can take the form of physical cash being *transported*.  While an electronic transfer has no physical transport.

Comment: Transfer is TCP but Transmit is UDP :))

Answer (score 2):

When writing legal documents, lawyers have to anticipate loopholes. In this case they are making sure that they cover both physical transfer of funds and those performed by transmitting information over electronic media. It is better in legal terms to be exhaustive and even redundant than to allow some cases to slip through the net.

Answer (score 2):

According to Collins:

***[transfer](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/transfer)***

> verb
>    (trænsˈfɜː ) , -fers -ferring or -ferred
>
> 1) to change or go or cause to change or go from one thing, person, or point to another"   ⇒  ■ they transferred from the Park Hotel to the Imperial", "   ⇒  ■ she transferred her affections to her dog"
>       2) to change (buses, trains, etc)
>       3) (law) to make over (property, etc) to another; convey
>       4) to displace (a drawing, design, etc) from one surface to another
>       (of a football player, esp a professional) to change clubs or (of a club, manager, etc) to sell or release (a player) to another club
>       5) to leave one school, college, etc, and enrol at another
>       to change (the meaning of a word, etc), esp by metaphorical extension

***[transport](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/transport)***

> verb
>    (trænsˈpɔːt )  (transitive)
>
> 1) to carry or cause to go from one place to another, esp over some distance

So, if both you and me had an account at the same bank, you could transfer me funds without actually transporting anything. As chasly says, redacting it like this avoids loopholes

Comment: My interest was usage of transfer vs. transmit @SamuelVimes

Answer (score 2):

From [Criminal Finance:The Political Economy of Money Laundering in a Comparative](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Cx3x4EijpXsC&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=money%20laundering%20transport%20transmit%20transfer&source=bl&ots=LiMysSdGo4&sig=V2gQPqaawN71bRex6wlDAHhswGc&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=money%20laundering%20transport%20transmit%20transfer&f=false), by Kris Hinterseer:

[image]